# How to reduce cost of AWS website hosting (EC2, RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS, so I have a few questions. I am hosting one static website, and one dynamic website from a single AWS t2.micro EC2 instance. I am also hosting a small (~5,000 entries) MySQL database on AWS RDS (db.t2.micro). The issue is that I am being charged around $40 per month for hosting these two low-traffic sites and a very small database. The majority of traffic coming to these sites is from my personal testing. This cost seems absurd. Below is my billing statements.

[image: AWS Billing Statement]

I am wondering a few things:

- Am I correct to believe I am paying too much, and if so, how can I reduce the cost?
- Am I paying too much because I am using the wrong instance sizing?
- Should I be using a different service to accomplish these tasks?

I see that I am being charged ~$17 for elastic load balancing. I am not sure if that is necessary, though I couldn't find any resources for how to decrease that cost/eliminate it.

Any help I can get is really appreciated, and if theres anymore information I can provide let me know!

Comment: You already have the smallest / cheapest of everything. The only options you have are to switch to a different service vendor or remove services such as ELB or RDS.

Comment: What would be the consequences of removing ELB?

Comment: @JohnHanley actually he could downgrade from t2.micro to t2.nano, but that will only save a few dollars a month.

Comment: The load balancer can provide additional benefits such as SSL offloading (reduces CPU load on your instance) and DoS (Denial of Service) from hackers hitting your site (which I find a big plus). If money is really that tight, I would drop the ELB and switch to CDN.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it doesn’t have anything even remotely to do with programming. Consider posting to serverfault.com where you will find a more appropriate audience.

Comment: @MarkB - I overlooked switching to nano (I never use that small of an instance).

Comment: @SamHollenbach You seem to be saying that the cost is absurd because your site doesn't get much traffic. You aren't being charged for traffic at all though, you are being charged for the server resources Amazon is dedicating to your account 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. You could probably run the entire site of a single t2.nano server (no ELB or RDS), purchase an instance reservation for that, and only pay about $4-$5 a month.

Comment: @SamHollenbach When you move this off-topic question to server fault, you need to include specifics about what type of software you are running your website with. My guess is Wordpress. You probably need to move to a single AWS Lightsail instance, or a single Digital Ocean dropplet.

Comment: @MarkB It is running on Flask with a Flask-restful API.

Comment: @SamHollenbach install MySQL on the same server as the application and get rid of RDS, then install an SSL certification using Lets Encrypt, and get rid of the load balancer. That would greatly reduce your costs. Just make sure you understand what you are doing and creating good backups, because RDS won't be there to save you anymore if something goes wrong.

Comment: This isn't a good question for ServerFault either, as that site is for professional administrators. More of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a few things that you may be able to do, but without understanding your application it's hard to be specific.

1. You might be able to use Spot/Reserved instances to save your EC2 costs.Take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ to see how the pricing model differs between On Demand and Spot/Reserved.
2. If possible, consider moving to serverless. Something like Lambda + API Gateway + S3 static web hosting. In the serverless payment model, you only pay for what you use rather than paying by the hour. If your application has low traffic, this could save you a lot of money.
3. If your application is being rarely used right now, consider using Aurora Serverless for your RDS. It runs MySQL and has the ability to "pause" the database when it is unused for a set amount of time. You're only charged for storage while the database is inactive, so if your traffic is low this could be a good save.
4. If your data structure allows for it, consider moving to DynamoDB. It's a NoSQL database which is essentially a key-value store. DynamoDB is serverless, and you only pay for what you use if you provision it to be On Demand. If you're not familiar with DynamoDB, you could take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/ which explains how to structure your data.

Comment: Thanks for these tips, really helpful! I have a static website that is simply a personal portfolio, and then I have a dynamic website that is essentially querying a MySQL database and displaying charts, along with some data input forms.

Comment: @SamHollenbach The Lambda + API Gateway + S3 could still work for your dynamic website. You'll just need to call an API from your frontend and pass it onto a Lambda through API Gateway, and let your Lambda call your database to make a query. One thing that you should be aware of though, is that a Lambda that runs inside a VPC is generally known to be quite slow on a cold start. 

If you do end up experimenting with this, I suggest that you take a look at how to keep a Lambda function warm. You'll get much better latency with minimal costs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am wondering if you know off hand how the pricing of that method would compare to just using EC2? I don't want to go through the trouble of converting all of my code if I am only saving a couple dollars.

Comment: It really depends on the level of traffic on your application. Making it really generic, 

Lambda: You get 1 million requests free per month, and from then on it costs $0.20/Million requests. (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)

API Gateway: You'll most likely only pay $3.50/Million requests (https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/)

S3: You probably don't even have to worry about costs for this (https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=4).

Comment: Beware that spot instances may go away at any time. Unless you know that you have a workload that can deal with this (and a personal website definitely isn't), then you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 2):

The elastic load balancing seems a bit much.
What are you using it for? 
I believe you can find the instances on the EC2 menu on the left. If you don't see it, try and switch between aws zones that you use or used in the past.

I would also suggest to host the sites in S3 as it's much cheaper then EC2. 
If not possible, then perhaps a combination of API gateway and Lambda functions could do the trick.

Comment: I am just using it for the single instance that is hosting both my websites. I believe I can move the static website to S3, but the dynamic site seems like it would need something else.

Comment: For the dynamic I would use API gateway and Lambda functions, like I see others have also suggested. It would be a hustle to set up but the cost will be close to zero.